# Strange bracket-parentheses notation in C++, looking somewhat like a for each loop

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

So this is how the code looks:

```
auto generateHash = [](std::vector<File> &files) -> std::shared_ptr<std::string> {
    // Other code here
}
```

What does this mean? Is it a for each loop? What do the brackets in the beginning do? What do the parentheses do? What does the arrow mean? I can't compile it because of no C++11 compiler, and I can't find it in the C++ reference.

Comment: Its a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). First part ([]) is capture group, second (()) is arguments, third (->) is return type, then it is just the code.

Comment: It is called lambda expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It's a *lambda* - a function object. You can call it like a function with a a vector of files (passed by mutable reference, for some weird reason), and it a returns string (managed by a shared pointer, for some weird reason).

```
std::vector<File> files = get_some_files();
std::shared_ptr<std::string> hash = generateHash(files); // call the lambda
```

> Is it a for each loop?

No. That looks like

```
for (auto thing : sequence) {/* code */}
```

> What do the brackets in the beginning do?

They signify that it's a lambda. They can contain the *capture list* of local variables that you want to make available to the code inside the lambda.

> What does the arrow mean?

That's a *trailing return type*. In C++11, you can use that syntax with normal functions if you want; but it's the only way to specify a lambda's return type.

> I can't find it in the C++ reference.

It's right here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: That helps a ton, thanks! Is there any possibility of doing this in another way? I can't change the compiler to a C++11 one, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DonAlonzo: You can probably replace it with a normal function, if it doesn't need to capture anything. If it does, then you'll probably need to write a function class with a constructor that captures whatever is needed. You'll have to get rid of `shared_ptr` too, since that's also C++11 - but it would make more sense to return `string` by value anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is lambda function, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C++11 lambda function, for a tutorial on how they work, you can look at [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html), else for a pure reference you can look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

In your case it defines an anonymous function that takes in `std::vector<File> &files` and returns `std::shared_ptr<std::string>`, and assigns this function to `generateHash`. the `auto` keyword tells the compiler to derive the type of `generateHash` (it this case it makes for a simple shorthand). the empty brackets (`[]`) means that the lambda doesn't capture and local variables for use within the lambda.